# Random number Absolute 1 or -1

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, random, mathematical-optimization

The question is simple. I need one line command like,

```
Math.round((-Math.random() * 2))
```

,which in output **just** shows **1** and **-1**. I try to figure it out but it seems not an easy task! I can use IF command like,

```
demo = (Math.random()>.5)?(1):(-1);
```

but I need something faster,  like a math formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine anything faster than this:

```
var n:int = ((Math.random()*4)&2)-1;
```

No conditionals, no compares, no functions other than random()   :-)

And here is another one just to make you think about how it works:

```
var n:int = (((Math.random()*0xFFFFFFFF) & 0x80000000)>>30) | 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a faster way you can do it as this:

```
var n:Number=(int(Math.random()>=0.5)<<1)-1.0
```

How it works :
`Math.random()>=0.5` will return `true` or `false`

```
int(true) = 1
int(false) = 0
```

`<<1` will multiply the value by 2 so you have an `int` which is `2` or `0`

now substract `1.0` and you have a `number` that is `1.0` or -`1.0`

Here some live test with their speed: http://wonderfl.net/c/xdqv

Comment: Try this one in your benchmarker:  var n:int = ((Math.random()*0x7FFFFFFF)&2)-1;

Comment: There is nothing special about 0x7FFFFFFF, in fact to get an even spread, Math.random() should probably be multiplied by any power of two that is 4 or greater: 4, 8, 16, etc... such that the second bit is 1 as often as 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
Math.round(Math.random())*2-1;
```

But to be honest it's slower than the conditional method.

```
var referenceTime:int = getTimer();
var randomInt:int;
for (var i:int=0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    randomInt = (Math.random()>.5)?1:-1;
}

trace(getTimer()-referenceTime);  //122ms
referenceTime = getTimer();

for (i=0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    randomInt = Math.round(Math.random())*2-1;
}

trace(getTimer()-referenceTime);   //238ms
```

Comment: you know, the getTimer() function would save you a lot of typing :D

Comment: Hey! I didn't know this one! It must have been hiding :p Anyway you're cruelly making fun of me!

Answer (score 3):

Your second line (the ternary operator) is the fastest way to do this. If you're calling this a lot, then you can cache the Math.random() function like:

```
private var m_ran:Function = Math.random;
```

Or for the absolute quickest access, you can pregenerate an array of 100 (or 1000, whatever) results, then traverse the list whenever you need it. Something like:

```
private var m_nums:Vector.<int> = null;
private var m_total:int         = 100;
private var m_curr:int          = 0;

private function _init():void
{
    this.m_nums         = new Vector.<int>( this.m_total, true );
    var ran:Function    = Math.random;
    for( var i:int = 0; i < total; i++ )
        this.m_nums[i] = ( ran() > 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

public function getRandom():int
{
    this.m_curr++;
    if( this.m_curr >= this.m_total )
        this.m_curr = 0;
    return this.m_nums[this.m_curr];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(Math.random())*(maxValue-minValue+1))+minValue;
```

According to jonsca could be a problem to set -1 as integer...

Answer (score 1):

```
var n:int = int(Math.random()*2) - 1 | 1;
```